# VBA to prompt for DAT with no delimitation, add new sheet, and import the DAT

Tags: vba, excel

The code prompts the user to select an Excel file and five different DAT files. The Excel file is loaded onto a sheet, and then new sheets are supposed to be added for each of the DAT files to be imported to. The Excel file loads correctly, but the program errors out at the first DAT file import attempt.

The error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

This is where the error occurs:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    DIFN, Destination _
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
' Prompt user for files
    CAFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    DIFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESDI DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
    FOFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESFO DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
    FSFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESFS DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
    IPFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESIP DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
    PPFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESPP DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")

' Load Combined All
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(CAFN)

    'Now, transfer values from x to y:
    With x.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
        'Now, paste to y worksheet:
        y.Sheets("Start").Range("A1").Resize( _
            .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With

    'Close x:
    x.Close

    y.Sheets("Start").Name = "Combined All"

' Load DAT files
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "ESDI"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        DIFN, Destination _
        :=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "ESDI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 1, 9, 1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(3, 7, 7, 2, 10, 8, 3, 8, 40, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: what's the value of `DIFN` when you pass it into the `Connection:=` argument?

Comment: C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT

Comment: And is `DIFN` declare as? It needs to be String for this to work. If it's not a string `CStr(DIFN)` may work.

Comment: Added Dim DFIN As String before the beginning of the code above, still get the error.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is Dim DIFN As String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me (thank you to YowE3K and Scott Holtzman for pointing me in the right direction!):

```
' Prompt user for files
Dim CAFN As String
Dim DIFN As String
Dim FOFN As String
Dim FSFN As String
Dim IPFN As String
Dim PPFN As String

CAFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
DIFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESDI DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
FOFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESFO DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
FSFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESFS DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
IPFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESIP DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")
PPFN = Application.GetOpenFilename("ESPP DAT File (*.dat), *.dat")

' Load Combined All
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set y = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open(CAFN)

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
With x.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("Start").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

'Close x:
x.Close

y.Sheets("Start").Name = "Combined All"


' Load DAT files
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "ESDI"
    MsgBox ">>>" & "TEXT;" & DIFN & "<<<"
    With Sheets("ESDI").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & DIFN, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "ESDI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 1, 9, 1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(3, 7, 7, 2, 10, 8, 3, 8, 40, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you are opening is a text file

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    DIFN, Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
```

should be replaced with

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & DIFN, _
                                 Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I still get the error. The file is a .dat file, if that makes a difference.

Comment: The file extension doesn't really make any difference, just what is contained in the file.  All your code following the "With" statement made me think it must have been a column-delimited text file.  If it isn't a text file, you still need to specify what sort of file it is - see [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx).

Comment: Ah, yes it is text.

Comment: I just ran the following code in a new workbook, and it worked:  `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "ESDI"`
`With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT;L:\xxxx.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))`  `.Name = "ESDI"`  `End With`

Comment: So that raises the questions:  Does "C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT" exist?  Is it accessible?  Is it not read-only?  (Probably raises other questions too - but they are a good start.)

Comment: That works for me too, if I plug in the exact file location rather than use the variable. The variable doesn't work, though. I need the variable to work because the file location is provided by the user.

Comment: But if, as you said, the variable DIFN contains the string `C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT` then there is no difference between saying `"TEXT;" & DIFN` and `"TEXT;C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT"`

Comment: Place a `MsgBox ">>>" & "TEXT;" & DIFN & "<<<"` immediately before your QueryTables.Add statement and let us know what it says

Comment: >>>TEXT;C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT<<<

Comment: OK, I'm stumped.  If you managed to get your code to work by replacing `"TEXT;" & DIFN` with `"TEXT;C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT"`, and the MsgBox shows that `"TEXT;" & DIFN` is `"TEXT;C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT"`, then I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm stumped, too. When stepping through the code, the run-time error occurs immediately after the line: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: OK - that is a completely different issue to the QueryTables.Add crashing.  That is now an issue with what you are **doing** with the QueryTable, rather than an issue in **creating** the QueryTable.  I don't know anything about QueryTables or how they are used, so I will have to let someone else answer you on that one.

Comment: Thanks, YowE3K. Your comments helped me fix the QueryTables.Add lines. Before, the error was happening at the With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add... line.

Comment: Having said that, I quickly looked at Microsoft's QueryTable documentation and the Refresh method says `Used only with QueryTables that are based on the results of a SQL query.`, so do you even **need** that line??

Comment: Well, removing the Refresh method removed the error, but now none of the data from the dat file is imported. Before I added the GetOpenFileName functionality and just having the file location coded directly without a variable, it was working well.

Comment: Hardcode the filename back in and see if it still works.  I.e. just make the minimal change to your code and use `"TEXT;C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESDIAPR.DAT"` in the spot where it says `"TEXT;" & DIFN` but don't make **any** other change.  (It can continue to do the GetOpenFileName function, but you just won't use the DIFN variable it sets.)

Comment: Tried that, no dice. Added a .Refresh and it worked!

Comment: All is good now. Not sure why, but the code I posted below is what did it, and I think your advice to change to "TEXT;" & DIFN was the key, so thanks!